# Accessing Object Properties VueJS

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I want to render a list, based on data I provide via my API. I made a screenshot of the current output. The problem is, that I cannot access my object properties. I get an error when loading the page. How do I access the properties correctly? `@{{incident.incidentReference}}` did not work.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ibox title="Einsätze">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Strasse</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr v-for="incident in incidents">
                    <td>@{{incident.incidentReference}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </ibox>
    </div>
</div>
```

**BASE.JS**

```
// IMPORT ADDONS
import VueEvents from 'vue-events';
import dashboard from './dashboard';
import gis from './gis';
import MFSApi from './mixins/MFSApi';

window.Vue = Vue;
Vue.use(VueEvents);

// Will be called if there is no initMap function in component
window.initMap = () => {
    true
}


var Base = window.App = new Vue({
    el: '#wrapper',

    mixins: [MFSApi],

    components: {
        dashboard,
        gis
    }
});
```

**COMPONENT DASHBOARD**

```
export default {
    name: 'dashboard',
    mixins: [MFSApi],

    template: "#dashboard",

    components: {
        ibox
    },

    data() {
        return {
            searchAddress: '',
            incidents: []
        }
    },

    mounted: function() {
        this.getAllIncidents(function(response) {
            this.incidents = response.data["data"];
        }.bind(this))
    },

    methods: {

    },

    created() {
        console.info('Dashboard component triggered');
    }
}
```

[image]

I have `incidents` defined in the Vue Code and loop through the objects that seem to be there according to what you can see above. But I cannot access the content of the objects.

The data I get from the server, when the component

[image]

The code for getting the data from the server via API:

```
export default {
    methods: {
        // Incidents
        getAllIncidents: function(callback) {
            axios.get('api/v1/incidents').then(response => callback(response));
        },

        createIncidentTicket: function(incidentData, callback) {
            axios.post('api/v1/incidents', incidentData).then(response => callback(response));
        }
    }
}
```

The code for the wrapper where everything is loaded into:

```
<!-- Wrapper-->
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        @include('layouts.navigation')

        <!-- Page wraper -->
        <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">

            <!-- Page wrapper -->
            @include('layouts.topnavbar')

            <!-- Main view  -->
            @yield('content')

            <!-- Footer -->
            @include('layouts.footer')

        </div>
        <!-- End page wrapper-->

    </div>
    <!-- End wrapper-->
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: You already get those objects, arent you? Just structure your html then, `<td>@{{ incident.incidentReference }}</td><td>@{{ incident.streetname }}</td>`

Comment: Ah sorry... forgot to mention the error. yep I would agree that is what I thought should work. The error is mentioned above

Comment: validate it first, could be it tries to render just before the array structured. `v-if="incidents.length > 0 && typeof incidents[0].incidentReference !== 'undefined" v-for....` or something like that

Comment: But wouldn't it then not render anything at all? The objects itself seem to be available as the table is populated

Comment: @sesc360 How do you know that? You're fetching data after this error occures (at this time it's empty `[]`), so you should validate it as mentioned above. When data is fetched your output will be updated.

Comment: Well I think that makes sense, but can I cover this within the VueJS file? Incidents is missing when loaded, as the component is not yet loaded when the page opens. but how can I capture this properly? I load the data from the API when the component is mounted, so it would explain when the table is accessing the variable that it is still empty.

Comment: If it's an empty array, then it should not throw the error you are seeing. That's how Vue works. [It won't even hit that part of the template until there is data](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/ybZaYN?editors=1010). I don't see the problem in what you have posted so far. Can we see what data you get back from the server? Or better yet would you show us working example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @BertEvans I just added the data I receive and the Base.vue where I load in the component. When the component is mounted, I load the data from the server as shown above. Therefore I thought the table accesses the variable earlier than the data is loaded.

Comment: What is the code for getAllIncidents?

Comment: @BertEvans Just added

Comment: It looks like you are importing a straight up javascript file for Dashboard. What is the full template for #wrapper?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144976/discussion-between-sesc360-and-bert-evans).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, the issue here was the template for the dashboard component was nested *inside* the template for the Vue. When Vue compiled the wrapper template, it was trying to compile the dashboard component as part of it's own template, which resulted in the error shown in the question.